# Why output shape of Conv2D is (None, 30, 30, 32) instead of (None, 30, 30, 32, 3) when input image of (32*32*3) is passed?

Tags: neural-networks

I am new to CNN deep learning. I was checking the summary of the model which i have built (as shown below). The input shape of our data is 32, 32, 3. Why output shape of `Conv2D` is (None, 30, 30, 32) instead of (None, 30, 30, 32, 3) when image of (32*32*3) is passed?

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 30, 30, 32)        896       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 15, 15, 32)       0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 13, 13, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 6, 6, 64)         0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 4, 4, 64)          36928     
                                                                 
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your input image be of shape $(h, w, c)$ where $h,w,c$ denote height and width of the image and the number of channels, respectively. Applying 2D covolutional layer to this actually means applying $c$ different filters indepedently to each of the channels and then summing up the results. That's why you don't see the dimension $c$ in the result. See [this related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326643/why-building-the-sum-of-a-filter-over-several-channels-in-a-convolutional-layer) on why we do that.